# Using Xcode, I'm trying to use 3 sliders (R, G, & B) to mix colors that will go in a UIImage box. Code is included

Tags: colors, uiimage, uicolor

Below is the code I'm trying to accomplish mixing R, G, & B to make a color that will be inserted into a UIImage box. I am new to programming and completely stumped with this one.

properties & slider actions:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *colorView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *redSlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *greenSlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *blueSlider;

- (IBAction)adjustRed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)adjustGreen:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)adjustBlue:(id)sender;
```

Slider variable assignment:

```
- (IBAction)adjustRed:(id)sender {
   NSString *redString;
   redString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.redSlider.value];
}

- (IBAction)adjustGreen:(id)sender {
   NSString *greenString;
   greenString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.greenSlider.value];
}

- (IBAction)adjustBlue:(id)sender {
   NSString *blueString;
   blueString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.blueSlider.value];
}
```

Method assigning color to UIImage:

```
-(void) MixColor {
    self.colorView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:redString green:greenString             blue:blueString alpha:1];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your action method create a *local variable* (`redString`, ...) that is not 
accessible in the `mixColor` method.

More important, a `UIColor` is created from floating point values in the range 0.0 .. 1.0 (and not from *strings*) for the R, G, B, A components

To update the color from the slider values, simply use

```
-(void) mixColor
{
    self.colorView.backgroundColor =
               [UIColor colorWithRed:self.redSlider.value
                               green:self.greenSlider.value
                                blue:self.blueSlider.value
                               alpha:1];
}
```

(assuming that the sliders have the default minimum value of 0.0 and maximum value of 1.0). Then call this method from all slider action methods:

```
- (IBAction)adjustRed:(id)sender
{
    [self mixColor];
}
```

and similarly for the other sliders.

Actually, you can connect all sliders to the *same* action method which updates
the color of the image view.